# How to append & update JSON file

Tags: python, json, python-2.7

I have below json file format , depending on input args I need to append emp_email's if the key matches , if no match then append at end.

```
    {
  "key1": {
    "emp_email": [
      "xxxx@email.com",
      "yyyy@email.com"
    ]
  },
  "key2": {
    "emp_email": [
      "aaaaa@email.com",
      "bbbbb@email.com"
    ]
  }
}
```

input_key = 'key2'

emp_email = 'cccc@email.com'

Above email 'cccc@email.com' needs to be updated for key key2 along with 2 existing email

input_key = 'key3'

emp_email = 'cccc@email.com'

This should append a new key value pair at end of JSON

```
    {
  "key1": {
    "emp_email": [
      "xxxx@email.com",
      "yyyy@email.com"
    ]
  },
  "key2": {
    "emp_email": [
      "aaaaa@email.com",
      "bbbbb@email.com"
    ]
  },
  "key3": {
    "emp_email": [
      "ccccc@email.com"
    ]
  }
}
```

I started with below code

```
try:
    json_file_read = open(json_file, "r")
    json_data = json.load(json_file_read)
except ValueError as e:
    print "Invalid JSON"
except IOError as e:
    print "File Not Present"


key_list = []
for key, value in json_data.items():
    key_list.append(key)
existing_key = " ".join(key_list)
existing_key_list = existing_key.split()
print(existing_key_list)

email_list = emp_email.split(",")
print email_list

for f in input_key.split(","):
    if f in existing_key_list:
        print "key exists...!!!"
        existing_email_list = json_data[f]["emp_email"]
        # create new appended list (new + existing)
        new_email_list = email_list + list(set(existing_email_list) - set(email_list))
        # not sure how to append for the specific key

    else:
        print "new key"
        # append the new key & email block at end
```

Comment: What is `space_list`, should that be `key_list`?

Comment: Can you be more specific about what the problem is? Why are you using Python 2, by the way?

Comment: @Barmar fixed the typo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no need to create a list of keys. You can just use `if f in json_data:` to tell if the key exists.

```
for i, key in enumerate(input_key.split(",")):
    if key in json_data:
        print "key exists!"
        json_data[key]['emp_email'].append(email_list[i])
    else:
        print "new key"
        json_data[key] = {'emp_email': [email_list[i]]}
```